# Autoload não encontra classe PSR-0

Tags: php, composer, php-autoload

Fiz uma aplicação utilizando composer com autload, configurei o arquivo composer.js e defini as namespace corretamente, porém na execução do código uma das classes não é encontrada gerando o erro abaixo.

Erro Fatal error: Class 'SON\Init\Bootstrap' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pj\App\init.php on line 7

Composer.js

```
{
    "name": "son/mvc",
    "require":{
        "php": ">=7.2"
    },

    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Evandro Ignacio",
            "email": "eignacio403@gmail.com"
        }
    ],

    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
         "SON" : "vendor/",
         "App" : ""
        }
    }, 
    "config": {
        "bin-dir":"bin"
    }

}
```

autoload_static.php

```
<?php

// autoload_static.php @generated by Composer

namespace Composer\Autoload;

class ComposerStaticInit25747fe376eb11119c2042d9135ae04d
{
    public static $prefixesPsr0 = array (
        'S' => 
        array (
            'SON\\' => 
            array (
                0 => 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pj\\vendor',
            ),
        ),
        'A' => 
        array (
            'App\\' => 
            array (
                0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/',
            ),
        ),
    );

    public static function getInitializer(ClassLoader $loader)
    {
        return \Closure::bind(function () use ($loader) {
            $loader->prefixesPsr0 = ComposerStaticInit25747fe376eb11119c2042d9135ae04d::$prefixesPsr0;

        }, null, ClassLoader::class);
    }
}
```

Chamada

```
<?php

namespace App;

use SON\Init\Bootstrap;

class Init extends Bootstrap{ // o erro acontece aqui

    protected function initRoutes(){
        $ar['home'] = array ('route' =>'/','controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'index');
        $ar['pedidos'] = array('route' =>'/pedidos', 'controller' => 'index', 'action'=> 'pedidos');
        $this->setRoutes($ar);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O *autoload* PSR-0, apesar de funcionar, está defasado. Use o *autoload PSR-4*. A sintaxe de instalação é um pouco diferente:

Crie o arquivo `composer.json` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "SON\\" : "vendor/",
            "App\\" : "App"
        }
    }
}
```

Abra o terminal/prompt de comandos e rode o comando: `composer install` e aguarde:

[image: Rodando a instalação do composer]

A estrutura do seu projeto vai ficar assim:

```
App/                (suas classes - chamada no php: use App\*)
public_html/        (arquivos públicos como index.php, *.css, *.js, *.png, etc)
vendor              (autoload.php - chamada no php: use SON\*)
vendor/Init         (Bootstrap - chamada no php: use SON\Init\*)
vendor/composer     (autoload requireds)
```

Agora é só requerer o autoloader no seu `index.php`:

```
<?php
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
```

Obs: não recomendo você editar nenhum dos arquivos do autoload. Tudo deve funcionar do jeito que vem na instalação. Se não funcionar, você fez algo errado e não deve fazer uma "gambi" nos arquivos do autoload.

Answer (score -1):

A sintaxe do autoload está errada tenta usar essa:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
   "SON\\" : "vendor/",
   "App\\" : ""
  }  
},
```

Alias, não é recomendavel utilizar a psr-0, pois foi descontinuada. É melhor utilizar a psr-4.